# breezeJS - anyway to know when an entity is finished committing after executing entityAspect.acceptChanges

Tags: javascript, breeze

It looks like acceptChanges method returns undefined. Is there any way to execute a callback on the commit? It seems like it would be proper for it to return a promise...

So anyway to do something like:

```
entity.entityAspect.acceptChanges().then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

A promise would be convenient but you can listen for the "entityChanged" event fired by the EntityManager when acceptChanges finishes and do your logic there.

Have a look at the acceptChanges source code here to see what it does  http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/files/a30_entityAspect.js.html#l194

Comment: Do you know if acceptChanges actually commits to the server? The docs say that the changes are committed but the code (and actual implementation) implies that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `acceptChanges` method does not commit changes to the server.  That's why it is not async, and does not return a promise.  If you want to run some code after acceptChanges completes, just write it on the next line:

```
entity.entityAspect.acceptChanges();
entity.description = "fresh";  // runs after acceptChanges
```

The `acceptChanges` method just sets the [EntityState](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html#entitystate) of the entities to Unchanged and clears the [original values](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html#original-values) map.  It's like pretending that the entity was saved.

The [saveChanges](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/lap-savechanges.html) method **does** commit changes to the server and **is** async and **does** return a promise.